# Performing OCR on gas meter

Tags: image, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I want to perform OCR on a gas meter so it can read the value. An example of a meter I want to perform OCR on:

[image: Meter]

The OCR should return 25539144 in this case.

As you can see there is a bit of a problem: There is a lot of text around the meter. So a normal OCR library wouldn't work here since it would return the text around it aswell.

I already tried object detection to detect the meter but the only one that seems to work well (because I have only 50 pictures) is the azure cognitive services. The problem is that later on it should be able to detect it in a live stream so a web service is not possible.

Can anyone help me in the right direction to tackle this problem?

Comment: I am considering if you could have some boost from the color: The color of the digits and their background. Do some feature engineering, and you don't need a lot of pictures for training since digital number detection is quite a sophisticated technique. I would start with threshold out the area that contains these digits. good luck.

Comment: Seems like a kind of similar problem to ANPR (automated number plate recognition) in a way. You know roughly the format you expect, and there's likely to be other text - ANPR faces the same challenge. Maybe you could make use of an existing ANPR framework and retrain/transfer learn? For example, 
https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr

Comment: I have similar requirements and searching for possible helping stuff, please let me know how you achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If the comment about using the colour doesn't help you then you could try this approach:

One possible approach could be to train a model (a NN perhaps) to draw a bounding box around the usage numbers.

You're going to have to draw a few boxes by hand to provide training examples.

Once you've run this "bounding-box creation model" you can crop out all the irrelevant stuff and you'll have a new training set consisting of examples that are easier to learn from.

You can then try retraining your ocr model on this new dataset.

Comment: I tried this with the azure cognitive services. That worked quite well but is online unfortunately. When I tried it with TensorFlow it didn't go that well. I am quite tempted to just scrap the live image feed and make it still image only.

Comment: have you tried just using keras? it might be a bit easier than using TF from scratch (unless you have to use TF). Also, could you just ocr on the entire thing and then grep for an 8 digit number?

Comment: The problem with OCR on the whole image is that it read's some images as a B instead of an 8. So I can't just regex it.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but maybe helpful to someone. I've been googling and researching the exact same problem for some time. Seems like it should all be possible with some OCR library and maybe OpenCV to detect the Region of interest first. However, for me the simplest solution is to physically tape off the parts that are not relevant. I know this is a totally stupid solution, but I prefer that to a complex system that is not 100% reliable.

I do recognize that this does not solve the generic problem but is super simple to do if

1. you have physical access to the meter
2. no one minds that you tape off the irrelevant parts ;)

Sometimes engineers (me included) try to find the perfect solution when there is a very simple and practical solution to the underlying problem.